# Cannot use feeds to import into data tables where the primary key is multiple

Tags: 7, feeds

I am using [Data Module](https://drupal.org/project/data) to create tables in Drupal.
Now, I need to import some data through CSVs, for this I want to use [Feeds Module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds). 
My table consists of more than one primary key i.e. a group of fields together forms a primary key.

Is there any way to import the data for such a case using feeds? Coz my understanding is that feeds cannot import data if the primary keys are not restricted into a single column.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to use [Feeds Tamper's](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) Rewrite plugin to combine the unique fields in your source into one field and then map that to the GUID.

https://drupal.org/node/1539224 could use some help as well for supporting this properly.